# Tabulator - HeaderSorting

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I am making many raw html tables and converting them to tabulator using

```
var table = new Tabulator("#main", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
    tooltipsHeader:true,
    pagination:"local",
    paginationSize:10,
    persistenceMode:"true",
});
```

and have to disable header sorting on a few of them.

Documentation and answers for similar questions all point to using

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", headerSort:false}
```

for the columns you want to turn of the sorting on.

What I want to do is but does not work

```
var table = new Tabulator("#main", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
    tooltipsHeader:true,
    pagination:"local",
    paginationSize:10,
    persistenceMode:"true",
    headerSorting:"false",
});
```

Question:  Can I disable sorting on a given table via initialization parameter like similar to code above or is it only possible by initializing each column, which I dont want to do since the tables are quite a few and have different dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<th tabulator-headersort="false" >@ColumnName</th>
```

is the correct method of doing this 
when converting Razor generated HTML tables to JS tabulator tables, and turning off the headers. The docs dont go well over the usage the tabulator- HTML attribute so some people might not be

There was a bugfix in Tabulator 4.2 so that camelcased attributes would work with HTML>Tabulator conversions. tabulator-headerSort is an example of that didn't work before the 4.2 bufix. It's a pretty neat way of doing custom tables based on what the razor model returns instead of doing it all in the JS

Answer (score 0):

You should give `headerSort: false` in the column definition every time you create a table but if you really want to remove sort button you can run the below code

```js
const tabledata1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli ",
    money: "0",
    col: "red",
    dob: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary ",
    money: "0",
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine ",
    money: "0",
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon ",
    money: "0",
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret ",
    money: "0",
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];

const col1 = [ //Define Table Columns
  {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  },
  {
    title: "money",
    field: "money",
    align: "left",
    formatter: "money"
  },
  {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  },
  {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    align: "center"
  },
];

const col2 = [ //Define Table Columns
  {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150,
    headerSort: false
  },
  {
    title: "money",
    field: "money",
    align: "left",
    formatter: "money",
    headerSort: false

  },
  {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col",
    headerSort: false

  },
  {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    align: "center",
    headerSort: false

  },
];
const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns: col1
});
const removeArrow = function() {
  table.setColumns(col2);
}


$('#removeArrow').click(function() {
  removeArrow();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>

  <button id="removeArrow">Change Column Definition</button>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While that removes the arrow it does not disable the header sorting action.

I would include haederSort : false if I could.  But my tables have change and can have different columns depending what the user asks for.

I'm trying to avoid defining every single type of table and their columns and maintaining it in the future.

Comment: Ok, that seems like it has potential.  Ill implement a version of this and get back to you.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution to my problem.  No extra defining columns.

Just added this to my th tags:

```
<th tabulator-headersort="false" >@ColumnName</th>
```

Tabulator grabs that attribute on the element and does exactly what I wanted.

Using version 4.2 fyi

Comment: There are no tables and <th> or <tr> or <td> in Tabulator library, Maybe you are using a different library

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. 

What I am doing is creating tables with Razor,  simple html tables.  Then Im using Tabulator to convert my basic vanilla tables into Tabulator tables.

<table id="MainTable">
    <thead>
        <th>ColumnA</th>
        <th>ColumnB</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dolor</td>
        <td>Sit</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

and Then
    
    var table = new Tabulator("#MainTable", {
        layout: "fitColumns",
        tooltipsHeader: true
 
    });